# Code from ICCV7- AVR displays garbled in text editor?

Tags: winavr, source-insight

I have code written for Atmega64 , with "ICCV7 for AVR" (C Cross Compiler for the Atmel AVR),

I can also open and edit it with sourceInsight,

but when I open it with text editor (the most common one on Windows),  it is all garbled.

What can I do ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your code file is stored in unix format, which uses "\n" as return at the end of each line. But notepad in windows uses "\r\n" as return. So in notepad, all the code may display in a single line.

PS: try to tag your Q with other tags. 'icc' here means Intel C++ Compiler.